# how to cache remote packages in Artifactory local repository?

Tags: java, maven, artifactory, artifacts

I've used Artifactory to setup a local repository on my server to let clients download java packages from it. 
I deployed a jar file to it and clients were able to get the jar file from the server. 
In case that a client **requests** for a package and it does not exist in the local repository, does the local repository download it from central repository and cache it for further requests? How can I ensure that? And where is it keeping these packages? I didn't found it in its default repositories.

And BTW, is this feature enabled by default or we should configure Artificatory to enable this feature?

**UPDATE**: 
I monitored requests log and in cases that a package exists in the repository, user can download it and the GET request status is 200 . But when a package does not exist in repository, the GET request will respond 404 and we expect that the package should be downloaded to local repository for further requests. But it is still responding 404 which means that it is not caching the package and user is downloading it from central repository directly without passing it through our local repository.

Comment: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories#ConfiguringRepositories-RemoteRepositories this might help.

Comment: Same here. The Artifactory generates a settings.xml file without the jcenter repo

Answer (score 6):

Artifactory separates [remote repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories#ConfiguringRepositories-RemoteRepositories) from [local repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories#ConfiguringRepositories-LocalRepositories). 
After defining remote repositories ([jcenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) is preconfigured, so you can skip this  step), accessing artifacts from the respective repositories (`http://host:port/artifactory/simple/jcenter/` or any of [the virtual repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories#ConfiguringRepositories-VirtualRepositories) `jcenter` is a part of) will trigger remote download. You will be able to see the downloaded artifact in the `jcenter-cache` repository in [the tree browser](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Browsing+Artifactory).

Please take a minute to read [the repositories documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories) to clearly understand the repository concept and the difference between local and remote repositories.

Comment: I didn't really mean searching. I meant requesting. Sorry about that.

Comment: If it is cached then where is it keeping these newly downloaded packages? I monitored request log. When package was in the repository everything was OK and user could download the package but when package did not exist in the repository, after that there was no request log which means that user was not downloading it from local repository which means that is was not cached.

Comment: I read the link you added, but the settings.xml file that was generated automatically by Artifactory doesnt have the jcenter.